# How do I turn on the "WLAN switch"?

Tags: ps-vita

To play multiplayer, my PS Vita is telling me to turn on the "WLAN switch". What is that and how do I turn it on? I've already tried changing the Ad-Hoc channel and turning Airplane Mode on.

Comment: Find the wlan switch, and turn it on?

Comment: I think the problem is that the Vita doesn't have a physical WLAN switch like the PSP, hold the PShome button to bring up the menu and make sure that WiFi is switched on. (This only works on the latest firmware, you will have to go into settings otherwise)

Comment: @Colin Make that an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: i tried that and it says the same thing

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is that the Vita doesn't have a physical WLAN switch like the PSP, hold the PShome button to bring up the menu and make sure that WiFi is switched on. (This only works on the latest firmware, you will have to go into the settings menu otherwise)

Edit: You have to make sure that airplane mode is off.

Comment: i tried that and it still doesnt work